# How can I restore Tensors to a past value, without saving the value to disk?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm doing some experimentation with TensorFlow, and have run into a snag. I'm trying to use TF to evalute a change in a model, then either retain or revert the model, based on the resultant change in loss function. I've got the hard part (conditional control) figured out, but I'm stuck on something that should be fairly straightforward: I can't seem to store a `tf.trainable_variables` for an iteration, then restore it if needed.

Let's say a build an Op:

```
...
store_trainable_vars = []

for v in tf.trainable_variables():

    store_trainable_vars.append(v)
...
```

Then later, I want to restore `tf.trainable_variables` to the value it had when this Op was last run. I'd want to do something like:

```
 def reject_move():

    revert_state = []

    for (v, s) in zip(tf.trainable_variables(), store_trainable_vars):

        revert_state.append(tf.assign(v, s, name="revert_state"))

    return(revert_state)
```

Obviously, this will re-evaluate `store_trainable_vars`, which in turn links to the present value of `tf.trainable_variables()`, obviating the `revert_state` Op. I need some way to store and retrieve the value of Tensors without calling back to the present value of those Tensors. Something like

```
...
store_trainable_vars = []

for v in tf.trainable_variables():

    store_trainable_vars.append(v.value_right_now())
...
```

where `v.value_right_now()` returns a constant that won't change until overwritten.

I know I could use Saver, but that solution writes to the disk, which is not acceptable for this application as it will run inside a training loop.

I'm probably missing something obvious - any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't my original intent to answer this question myself, but I've come up with a method that works fairly well. So, I thought I'd share it. The key insight came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333803/3417688) very clever answer. The approach is to reuse the assignment nodes created for inital variable assignment. A complete class implementing that approach is given below.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class TensorFlowState(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # Get the graph.
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        # Extract the global varibles from the graph.
        self.gvars = graph.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)

        # Exract the Assign operations for later use.
        self.assign_ops = [graph.get_operation_by_name(v.op.name + "/Assign")
                           for v in self.gvars]

        # Extract the initial value ops from each Assign op for later use.
        self.init_values = [op.inputs[1] for op in self.assign_ops]

    def start(self, sess):

        self.sess = sess

    def store(self):

        # Record the current state of the TF global varaibles
        self.state = self.sess.run(self.gvars)

    def restore(self):
    # Create a dictionary of the iniailizers and stored state of globals.
    feed_dict = {init_value: val
                 for init_value, val in zip(self.init_values, self.state)}

    # Use the initializer ops for each variable to load the stored values.
    return(self.sess.run(self.assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict))
```

To use, simply instantiate the class, call the `start` method to pass a `tf.Session`, and call the `store` and `restore` methods as needed inside your imperative training loop. I've used this implementation to build an optimizer, which runs about as fast as the gradient descent optimizers included with TensorFlow.

Answer (score 5):

To restore a graph state manually you need to use [`tf.tuple`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tuple) or [`tf.group`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) operation, that will modify the flow for a bulk change:

> This creates a tuple of tensors with the same values as the tensors
>   argument, except that the value of each tensor is only returned after
>   the values of all tensors have been computed.

**[Update]** Here's how I would do it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
W = tf.Variable(np.zeros([5, 5]), dtype=tf.float32, name='W')
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([5]), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)

with tf.Session() as session:
  batch = np.ones([2, 5])
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print session.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch})      # prints [2, 5] zeros

  # store the current value
  store = {v.name: v.eval(session) for v in tf.trainable_variables()}
  print store                                     # prints [5, 5] and [5] zeros

  # update
  new = {'W:0': np.ones([5, 5]), 'b:0': np.ones([5])}
  session.run(tf.tuple([tf.assign(var, new[var.name]) for var in tf.trainable_variables()]))
  print session.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch})      # prints [2, 5] sixes

  # restore
  session.run(tf.tuple([tf.assign(var, store[var.name]) for var in tf.trainable_variables()]))
  print session.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch})      # prints [2, 5] zeros again
```

But I really think you should reconsider your decision about `Saver`, because it was designed to be used inside a training loop as well. Internally, `Saver` does all the tricky work for you (in particular, it's restore op calls `tf.group` and `tf.control_dependencies` if needed), which may otherwise become the source of pretty nasty bugs. Besides, the disk is (almost) always bigger than your GPU and main memory, so if you can afford to store the model in memory, you should be able to store on disk as well.

Here are [some parameters](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) that help to control the proliferation of checkpoint files on disk:

- `max_to_keep` indicates the maximum number of recent checkpoint files to
  keep.  As new files are created, older files are deleted.  If None or 0, all checkpoint files are kept. Defaults to 5 (that is, the 5 most recent
  checkpoint files are kept).
- `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours`: In addition to keeping the most recent
  `max_to_keep` checkpoint files, you might want to keep one checkpoint file
  for every N hours of training.  This can be useful if you want to later
  analyze how a model progressed during a long training session.  For
  example, passing `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=2` ensures that you keep one checkpoint file for every 2 hours of training.  The default value of 10,000 hours effectively disables the feature.

**[Update]** As clarified in the comments, the main concern is disk latency, that may slow down the training if accessed too often. If you're using Linux, it [caches](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics) frequently used disk pages, [Windows does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666042/disable-or-flush-page-cache-on-windows) as well. But if you want to be absolutely sure, consider using [`tmpfs`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount).

Comment: I should clarify: when I said I didn't want to write to the disk, it wasn't becuase I was concerned about space. This storage and restoration will occur, in the worst case, on every iteration. It's the running time penalty for reaching back to the disk that I'm trying to avoid. Can you edit your answer to instead demonstrate a trivial use of `tf.group` for graph restoration? (or just link to such an example)