# How to clear the cache in Windows programatically?

Tags: java, windows, caching

I've read several posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574168/how-to-flush-the-disk-read-cache-under-windows) on how cache can be cleared using external applications.

I'd like to run a performance benchmark and would like to clear the operating file system cache before each run. I'm running a program in Java with many parameters, I need an automated method of doing this i.e. programatically in Java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use JNA to call [`SetSystemFileCacheSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`((SIZE_T) -1, (SIZE_T) -1, 0)`, which flushes the cache. But I don't think that's sufficient because it simply transitions the pages from the working set to the standby list, without actually purging them.

Comment: RAMMap uses an undocumented system call to purge the standby list, which I believe requires NT 6. See [this page](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html) for more info on the declarations required by the following snippet: `SYSTEM_MEMORY_LIST_COMMAND command = MemoryPurgeStandbyList;` `NtSetSystemInformation(SystemMemoryListInformation, &command, sizeof(command));` This requires `"SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege"` to be enabled, for which an elevated process needs to call `OpenProcessToken`, `LookupPrivilegeValue`, and `AdjustTokenPrivileges`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that calling `SetSystemFileCacheSize` to flush the cache requires enabling `"SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch file to clear cache and call that batch file in java.

here's a command to call batch file in java: [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start clearCache.bat");
```

this batch file will clear all `java cache` in `windows`. just call this batch file in your java code to execute

```
@Echo Off

echo =========================

echo Now clearing all users Java cache folder

set "docandset=%homedrive%\users"

     >> c:\Delete.log echo/ "Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%docandset%" /ad /b') do (

for %%b in (

"%docandset%\%%a\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0"

) do (

echo %%b >> c:\Delete.log

cd /d %%b >> c:\Delete.log  2>&1

rd /s /q %%b >> c:\Delete.log  2>&1

del /f /s /q %%b >> c:\Delete.log  2>&1

)

)

echo =========================

echo COMPLETE!!!! 

echo =========================

echo All users Java cache folder has been cleared.

PAUSE
```

found it here: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1928-clear-all-users-java-cache

you can check this also, clear windows temporary files: [Batch delete temporary Windows files (system, browsers, cache, etc) for all users](https://superuser.com/questions/832681/batch-delete-temporary-windows-files-system-browsers-cache-etc-for-all-user)

Comment: This comment appears to describe how to clear the Java cache from the disk, but I believe the question is asking how to clear the system file cache from memory.