# Determine the bottleneck in multiprocessing code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The task is to take records from the input file, process them and store in SQLite database. File can have millions of records, processing of one record is pretty fast, but I hope to gain some boost from multiprocessing. I implemented it and found that there is somewhere a bottleneck since the boost is not so big.

I cannot effectively utilize all cores. 3 processes give some noticeable effect, more processes already is not effective.

Below I provided the simplified example code just to show how processes are created and managed.

After some investigation I suspect:

1. data reading from the disk
2. serialization/unserialization - the least suspicious
3. data passing to processes
4. locks. I have two of them:

   - to write data to db and
   - to manage intermediate data in-memory which will be stored to db after the whole process was finished

What is not the bottleneck:

1. db writing

   - I made it by chunks and
   - replacement with in-memory database gave no speed gain

I profiled the code in single processes (with `cProfile`). It is not very useful. The most time is spent on calculation stage.

Measuring the time execution on small subset of data gave:

```
# (laptop, 2 cores with hyper-threading, Python 3.5, Ubuntu 16.04, SSD)
serial (old implementation): 28s
parallel (workers = 1): 28s
parallel (workers = 2): 19s
parallel (workers = 3): 17s
parallel (workers = 4): 17s

# (virtual machine on a server, 30 cores, Python 3.4, Ubuntu 14.04, HDD)
parallel (workers = 1): 28s
parallel (workers = 2): 11s
parallel (workers = 3): 10s
parallel (workers = 4):  8s
parallel (workers = 5):  8s
parallel (workers = 6):  8s
```

Q: How to determine what is a bottleneck or at least some of the suspected issues? Is it possible to obtain a better than 4-fold gain?

```
# indigo is an external module

def process(q, conn, cursor, d, lock_db, lock_dict):

    data_collector = []

    while True:

        data = q.get()

        if data is None:
            break

        mol_name = data[1]
        mol = indigo.unserialize(data[0])    # <-- unserialization

        lock_dict.acquire()
        value = d.get(mol_name, None)
        if value is None:
            value = calc_value(mol)
            d[name] = value
        lock_dict.release()

        # some calculations which return several variables A, B and C

        data_collector.append([mol_name, A, B, C])

        if len(data_collector) == 1000:
            insert_data(conn, cursor, data_collector, lock_db)
            data_collector = []

    insert_data(conn, cursor, data_collector, lock_db)




with lite.connect(out_fname) as conn:

    cur = conn.cursor()
    create_tables(cur)

    nprocess = max(min(ncpu, cpu_count()), 1)

    manager = Manager()
    lock_db = manager.Lock()
    lock_dict = manager.Lock()
    q = manager.Queue(2 * nprocess)
    d = manager.dict()

    pool = []
    for i in range(nprocess):
        p = Process(target=process, args=(q, conn, cur, d, lock_db, lock_dict))
        p.start()
        pool.append(p)

    for i, mol in enumerate(indigo.iterateSDFile(file_name)):
        q.put((mol.serialize(), mol.name())    # <-- serialization

    for _ in range(nprocess):
        q.put(None)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    for k, v in d.items():
        insert_db(cur, k, v)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Should this be on CodeReview?

Comment: I don't think so, since I didn't provide the complete code to run and test it. I'm asking about the ways how to determine the bottleneck in a multiprocess application, because profiling of multiprocessing code is not a simple task for me.

Comment: You say the profiling claims "The most time is spent on calculation stage." but we can't see that code either.

Comment: @doctorlove, there is lot of code. I can say it doesn't use locks and it is purely computational, no I/O. But it is pretty fast, less than ~0.01s per call (to process one record).

Comment: An observation - When you are reading from the disk - whatever you read is added to the OS Cache even if the handler is garbage collected.  I have a MT process that just slows down because the cache gets full, it takes a while because I have a lot of memory but it generally starts lagging.  I spent a ton of time trying to mess with GC and finally learned it was the OS not my Python code (Windows)

Comment: @PyNEwbie, and how did you solve this issue?

Comment: @DrDom Nothing, because it is not a problem solvable in programming with my skills.  Basically Windows has masterfully engineered a robust and persistent cache.  I did look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574168/how-to-flush-the-disk-read-cache-under-windows and ultimately decided that I was not going to fight the issue anymore.